# How to trigger a submit function from Custom Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to trigger the form submit function from `custom component`. 
In general my goal is to trigger a `boolean state value` which is a part of `form`, and even though the `custom component` is imported inside the form, somehow it doesn't work. 
Problem is about `sendEmail` function which comes from `Custom Component`

Here is the [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-shaw-qm4fwx?file=/src/App.js) and code example below.

Custom Component

```
import React from "react";

const CustomComponent = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={props.sendEmail} type="submit">
        send email
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CustomComponent;
```

App.js

```
import { useState } from "react";
import CustomComp from "./CustomComp";

export default function App() {
  const [isDone, setIsDone] = useState(false);
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsDone(true);
    console.log("inputText", inputText);
  };

  console.log(isDone);

  const sendEmail = () => { // this doesn't work
    handleSubmit();
    console.log("isDone", isDone);
  };

  const onChangeHandler = (e) => {
    setInputText(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <form>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <input type="text" onChange={onChangeHandler} value={inputText} />
      <CustomComp sendEmail={sendEmail} />
      <button onClick={handleSubmit} type="submit">
        submit
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You call `handleSubmit()` which means that `e` will be undefined. So `e.preventDefault()` causes a crash. I'm confused on what your goal is and why you have more than one submit button but you can eliminate the crash by moving the form submit logic into another function and calling that instead of calling `handleSubmit` with no arguments

Comment: Can you explain a little bit about "somehow it doesn't work". What isn't working how you expect it to? Are you getting logs that you don't expect, behavior that you don't understand, etc...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem you have is you're calling `handleSubmit` in the `sendEmail` without passing through `'e'`

I'd change to this:

```
const sendEmail = (e) => {
  handleSubmit(e);
  console.log("isDone", isDone);
};
```

After doing this, you'll notice your `isDone` isn't showing what you'd expect. This is because when you're changing the state via `handleSubmit`, it won't change within this call. You shouldn't worry about logging it as you have. It'll only be an issue if you need to do something with the `isDone` value

Answer (score 1):

There is no event passed when you trigger it from the custom component so `event.preventDefault()` will result in an error.

Add the event to `sendMail`, and pass it to `handleSubmit`. The `onClick` will automatically pass the event as first param:

```js
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setIsDone(true);
    console.log("inputText", inputText);
};

const sendEmail = (event) => {
    handleSubmit(event);
    console.log("isDone", isDone);
};
```

---

##### [Updated CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/charming-montalcini-gujgyg?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
There is one more thing i encountered, that in custom component setting button type as "submit" is mandatory to make it work.
Is it because it is a part of form?